# Two view points of exterior algebra - k-vectors and tangent spaces

Tags: differential-geometry, exterior-algebra

I'm trying to see how two ideas are related:

In (Discrete) Exterior Calculus, we defined k-vectors as volumes, and that k-forms are like "measurement tools", that allow us to measure k-vectors.

However, in Differential geometry, for a real differentiable $n$-manifold $M$, and $p \in M$, we first defined the tangent space $T_pM$, using either tangent-curves or derivations. We've proved that for a chart $(U,x)$, where $U$ is an open set of $M$, a basis for $T_p M$ is:
$$ \{ \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} \} \quad , i = 1 \ldots, n$$
Then we've defined the $k$th exterior power $\bigwedge ^k (T_p M)$, and we called its elements $(k,0)$-tensors.

What is the relation between the $(k,0)$-tensors of differential geometry and the $k$-vectors defined in exterior algebra? Can we say that wedging partial-differential operators are like "volumes" then?

Comment: You probably don’t want to think about them as volumes in the differential geometry context, because that idea should be reserved for the exterior power of the dual space. Algebraically, the two constructions are the same for the tangent space at a point though.